# Parsing a C function in Python

Tags: python, c, parsing

Say I want to parse a C function in a Python script and want to get a list with all the types of the arguments and only the arguments for the C function. How would I go about doing this efficiently?

E.g.: 
With this function

```
uint32_t foo(char a, int b, double* c, uint64_t d);
```

I want output `['char', 'int', 'double*', 'uint64_t']`

Comment: "Efficiently"? Well, just take your inefficient solution and clean it up.

Comment: `In [1]: proto="uint32_t foo(char a, int b, double* c, uint64_t d);"
In [2]: p = re.compile("(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(\s*(.*)\)")  # thanks to https://regex101.com/
In [3]: m = p.match(proto)
In [4]: m.groups()
Out[4]: ('uint32_t', 'foo', 'char a, int b, double* c, uint64_t d')
In [5]: list(map(lambda s: s.strip().split(' ')[0], m.group(3).split(',')))
Out[5]: ['char', 'int', 'double*', 'uint64_t']`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to parse the "prototype of a C function". When you say parse a "C function" ordinarily one would assume that you are doing what a compiler might do with the source implementation.

In your example, you only show a prototype. In the real world, you will encounter many complications that might make you choose another approach. Your killer is the C preprocessor. In an insane piece of code the real type of 'a' could actually be double* due to a really bad macro. You also might have pointers to structs, typedefs for function pointers, etc.

There is a complication that absolutely defies a solution to your problem. The compilation of the prototype will depend on command line arguments to a C compiler describing where to find header files. Without that metadata, you are hosed. With it, you would really want to run the C preprocessor first - check your compiler documentation for how to do so. Then your python program could read the output.

That line might not even be in it - LOL - if it happened to be surrounded by a #if construct that eliminated it.

These *features* of the C language are the features that make it really nasty to do things like write programs that operate on C, such as a refactoring engine.